# Magento 2.1 Payment Method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment

Considering a custom **Payment Method** class extending **`\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod`**: **Would somebody kindly explain what do the methods below do?**

**initialize(**`$paymentAction`**,** `$stateObject`**)**
**validate()**
**order(**`\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment`, `$amount`**)**
**authorize(**`\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment`**,** `$amount`**)**
**capture(**`\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment`, `$amount`**)**
**refund(**`\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment`, `$amount`**)**
**cancel(**`\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment`**)**
**void**(`\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment`**)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **initialize**: Instantiate state and set it to state object. Method that will be executed instead of authorize or capture if flag isInitializeNeeded set to true.
2. **validate**: Validate payment method information that means validate payment method is allowed for billing country or not.
3. **order**: Check order availability.
4. **authorize**: Payment process authorize only. After authorize, you need to capture amount manually.
5. **capture**: Capture payment amount. When this method called, system automatically capture amount.
6. **refund**: Refund specified amount for payment.
7. **cancel**: Cancel payment.
8. **void**: void specified amount for payment. Some payment method don't allow refund within 24hrs. So in that case you need to call void for refund that amount.

[Update]

**Where actually during checkout process does authorize and capture is being called?**

**Solution:**

Open **Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php** Check following method.

1. place
2. processAction

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just 2 questions:    1) What does '**void specified amount**' mean?     2) Where does '**capture**' actually being called?

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: 'void specified amount' mean -> you can specified how much you need to void.

Comment: Where actually during checkout process does **authorize** and **capture** is being called? For my module only **validate** is called!

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's as **deprecated** approach to extend `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod`, instead, you should use Magento payment gateway.

You can find the step-by-step guide how to implement payment method on [Magento 2 dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html) based on Magento payment gateway.

Also, Magento has `sale`(authorize & capture) payment action - it's similar to `authorize`, but allows process the capturing action for an authorized transaction.
This post describes how to implement `sale` payment action - https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/The-Magento-Sale-Payment-Operation/ba-p/67251.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll take a look into it. I've up-voted your answer.