# how to call specific payment model function on place order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am developing a custom payment module. I have successfully setup credit card form on checkout page but while I am placing an order, capture function of that payment model doesn't call.

You can check code here https://github.com/lalitkaushik/customcode

Is there anyone can help me to know how can I call capture function?

Edit: I have noticed that after installing the module in vanilla Magento setup, it's working only first time.

Comment: Please share your module

Comment: Where can I share module?

Comment: I have uploaded my code here : https://github.com/lalitkaushik/customcode

Comment: Hello @AmitBera, did you get chance to check shared code?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked your module over **Github** and there is a problem with your `etc/config.xml`.

As described [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/payment-option-config.html) in M2 Official Documentation, we need to define our payment method configurations in `etc/config.xml` and you did miss some of the configurations.

In order to invoke capture, we need to add `<can_capture>1</can_capture>` configuration in the `etc/config.xml` file.

After the necessary changes, your `etc/config.xml` will look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <dotsquares_mystripe>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>Dotsquares\Mystripe\Model\Payment</model>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <title>Paymetric Payment Method</title>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <!-- <api_key backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" /> -->
                <is_gateway>1</is_gateway>
                <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout>
                <can_authorize>1</can_authorize>
                <can_capture>1</can_capture>
                <can_refund>1</can_refund>
                <can_void>1</can_void>
                <can_cancel>1</can_cancel>
                <useccv>1</useccv>
                <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI,JCB</cctypes>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <min_order_total>0.50</min_order_total>
            </dotsquares_mystripe>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

You can also find short description of each of these method [here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156792)

I hope this will help.

Comment: It's not working at my end

Comment: I've tested it with M2.1.7 and it was working.  Flush cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your module here two things are missing i.e

add into `ete\adminhtml\system.xml`

```
<field id="payment_action" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Payment Action</label>
                <source_model>Dotsquares\Mystripe\Model\Source\PaymentAction</source_model>
</field>
```

Then write below code into `Dotsquares\Mystripe\Model\Source\PaymentAction.php`

```
namespace Dotsquares\Mystripe\Model\Source;

use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;

/**
* Class PaymentAction.
*
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class PaymentAction implements   \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
 /**
 * Possible actions on order place.
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return [
        [
            'value' => AbstractMethod::ACTION_AUTHORIZE,
            'label' => __('Authorize'),
        ],
        [
            'value' => AbstractMethod::ACTION_AUTHORIZE_CAPTURE,
            'label' => __('Authorize and Capture'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

}

Then select payment action from configuration and save it.